# Image weirdly changed after cv::resize()

Tags: c++, opencv

The related code is here(C++, opencv):

```
Rect rec = boundingRect(...);
image_grey.copyTo(gesture_grey, mask);
imshow("image_grey", gesture_grey(rec));
resize(gesture_grey(rec), gesture_grey, Size(256, 256));
imshow("gesture_grey", gesture_grey);
```

The result of imshow()：
[image]

Why are the two images so different before and after resizing? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `copyTo` method. It doesn't clear the content of 'gesture_grey' image container.

When you use `gesture_grey(rec)` you are effectively executing copy constructor, which gives you a new image container, so it's all cool. But when you call `copyTo` you are copying over to an existing target 'gesture_grey'.

To fix it, you need to re-initialize 'gesture_grey' in order to clear it, before calling `copyTo`. Otherwise, what you see is a combination of the previous content of 'gesture_grey' + new content you copy from `image_grey`.

Comment: I've tried your method but the results are still the same.

Comment: @ShiqingShen Your question doesn't tell how `gesture_grey` is initialized and what happens to it before `copyTo` method. Since `copyTo` method doesn't clear the target, I can only assume that what you see on the left image is a product of previous state of `gesture_grey` + `image_grey` + 'mask'. Try to re-initialize `gesture_grey` before 'copyTo' and see if it change anything.

Comment: @ShiqingShen would you mind to up-vote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Actually 'gesture_grey' is a class member and I didn't initialze it before these code. But I still don't quite understand the reason of the problem. I think 'copyTo' should initialze it for me.